# Integral of complex exponential in a proof of the cross-correlation theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis

I do not understand the link between the lines (4) and (5) in the proof of the [cross-correlation theorem found in Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cross-CorrelationTheorem.html):

```
![line4](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/Cross-CorrelationTheorem/Inline15.gif) (4)

![line5](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/Cross-CorrelationTheorem/Inline18.gif) (5)
```

*(I can't post the images of the equation because I don't have enough reputation)*

This confuses me because I thought $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{-2 \pi t} dt}$ was not defined. However the line (5) above implies this quantity is 0.

What don't I understand? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From line 4 to 5, the equality $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{2\pi i \tau (\nu'-\nu)}d\tau = \delta(\nu'-\nu)$$
is used, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.  The proof given is not rigorous.  As you remarked, the function $e^{2\pi i \tau}$ is not in $L^1(-\infty,\infty)$.  There are ways to make the equation above (under a suitable interpretation) and the proof itself work rigorously.  The step from line 5 to line 6 is also not completely rigorous (or you could say it has gaps).

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell me more about the suitable interpretation that gives sense to this equation?

Comment: Well, technically, you'd want to jump from step 3 to step 6 by assuming suitable decay of F and G at infinity, then the integrability of the exponential is not an issue.  If you don't have that decay, you can also use the Fourier transform on tempered distributions.